# Can mootools.js work with microsoftajax.js?

Tags: javascript, .net, mootools

There are mootools.js and microsoftajax.js scripts on one page. Basically I use microsoftajax.js so I can use classes and delegates etc. in script. Mootools is used by customer in her code.
It seems that those can't be together because I get `Type.createDelegate is not a function` error.
Is there solution for that?

UPDATE:
error is thrown in my script (script that makes use of microsoftajax.js)
mootools is in 1.3.2 version

Comment: What version of Mootools are you using ?

Comment: 1.3.2 but also 1.4.1 causes error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Type is a MooTools construct that is essential to definition of many things in core and more, including Class, Object, Function, Array, Number, String, Date, Table(Hash) etc.

It exists as a constructor in the global object:
https://github.com/mootools/mootools-core/blob/master/Source/Core/Core.js#L148

and is used like so (eg):
https://github.com/mootools/mootools-core/blob/master/Source/Class/Class.js#L19

anyway, does not matter to OP what Type is used for. the point is, if mootools is loaded after your other script, it *will* overwrite Type. on the other hand, if you load it before your script and don't need to create a new mootools Type, things may be ok.

you can always save a reference to it and restore it later.

eg:

```
var MooTools.Type = this.Type;

... load ms one.
... do stuff with `Type.createDelegate` etc
... restore mootools one:

this.Type = MooTools.Type;
```

p.s. wth is `microsoftajax.js` and why can't you use the mootools Request class instead? you cannot be a 1 toolbox dev these days.